# Proposition II.8.7 of Hartshorne and vanishing of Kähler differentials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

$\def\frm{\mathfrak{m}}$I don't understand the first line of the proof of Proposition II.8.7 of Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*.

[image]

(8.4A) is the conormal exact sequence:

[image]

We are assuming that there is $k\subset B$ with $k\cong B/\frm=\kappa$. But why does the composite $k\to B\to\kappa$ satisfy $\Omega_{\kappa/k}=0$? If for example $B$ was a localization of a finitely generated $k$-algebra, then $k\to\kappa$ would be (finite) algebraic by [this form](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00FV) of the Nullstellensatz. If we further assumed $k\to\kappa$ is separable, we would conclude $\Omega_{\kappa/k}=0$ (Matsumura's *Commutative Algebra*, (27.B), Theorem 59). In general, I don't know how to prove it. Maybe with “contains a field $k$ isomorphic to its residue field $B/\frm$” Hartshorne means that the morphism $k\to B/\frm$ is onto? (In general, it is not.¹) And there is some example where $\Omega_{\kappa/k}\neq 0$.

---

¹ Consider the field morphism $k(t)\to k(s)$ sending $t$ to $s^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the statement of Proposition 8.7 it is implicitly assumed that the composite $k \subset B\to  B/\mathfrak{m}=\kappa$ is an isomorphism (and this will certainly be true every time you try to use this result in practice). You can also see Exercise 8.1 in the same chapter for a generalisation.